# Each open covering of F has a finite subcovering, how can F not complete be a problem?

Tags: real-analysis

I understand that if for each open covering, $\mathcal{O}$, of a set $F$, which is subset of a metric space $(X,d)$, there is a finite subcovering $\implies F$ is compact $\implies F$ is complete $\implies$ all Cauchy sequences in $F$ converge.

In addition, assume $\sqrt{2}$ is not an element in $F$

Because $F$ is compact, I understand that $F$ has to be complete. Ie, if $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence which is Cauchy converging to $\sqrt{2}$, but $\sqrt{2}$ is not in $F$, then $\{x_n\}$ cannot be in $F$ because it is complete.

My question is: Assume for contradiction that the latter is the case -- there is one Cauchy sequence which does not converge to $\sqrt{2}$, how can this imply there is not a finite subcovering for each open covering of $F$?

If you could keep it as simple, short and intuative as possible, that would probably teach me the most -- I already think the open covering property is surprising way to prove compactness $\implies$ completeness.

Thank you for your time.

Kind regards,
Marius

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}$ that does not converge to a point. This necessarily implies there are infinitely many distinct elements of the sequence. It also implies that the set $\{x_n\}$ is closed (can you see why?), and hence if $X$ was compact, it would also be compact. Note that no subsequence can converge to a point $x$, because then the Cauchy-ness of the sequence implies the whole thing converges to $x$. So every distinct element $x_i$ contains an open set $U_i$ that contains no other elements of the sequence (can you see why?). The collection $\{U_n\}$ covers the set $\{x_n\}$ but clearly has no finite subcover, arriving at the conclusion that our space could not have been compact.

Remark: To show that a space is not compact, it suffices to exhibit a single open cover with no finite subcover. It is not in general true that every open cover will not have a finite subcover -- take the open cover with one open set.